# Struggling to get media through to whatsapp client

Tags: php, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am struggling to get the CURL to send media to my phone on `WhatsApp`. The body comes through the file but I can't seem to get the media through.

**Here is my code:**

```
$data = array (
    "To" => "whatsapp:+2783272####",
    "Body" => "check the owl out",
    "From" => "whatsapp:+14155238886", 
    "mediaUrl" => "https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png"
);

$post = http_build_query($data);
$x = curl_init('https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXX/Messages.json');

curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'eaXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

$result =  curl_exec($x);
```

All I receive to my phone is the body and not the Media. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'eaXXXXXXXXXXXX'); - that is meant to be:

curl_setopt($x, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ACXXXXXXXXX:eaXXXXXXXXXXXX');

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-php), there could be a couple of problems, but the most likely candidate is that `mediaUrl` should point to an array of strings, not just a string:

```php
$data = array (
            "To" => "whatsapp:+2783272####",
            "Body" => "check the owl out",
            "From" => "whatsapp:+14155238886", 
            "mediaUrl" => ["https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png"]
            );
```

If that isn't it, there are a couple of other notes in their documentation that might be relevant to you, too.

> If you joined your Sandbox more than 24 hours ago, you will need to send a fresh inbound message to your WhatsApp number in order to then send yourself a media message. WhatsApp currently does not support media in “template” messages that take place outside of a 24-hour session.

And this one:

> WhatsApp media content is currently only supported in Session Messages. If the WhatsApp session with a user expires, you must wait for an inbound message to create a new session before you can send them a media message.

Also, although you are of course free to use the low-level curl, you might get better debugging support if you use one of their [free](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) [SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php)

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried uses arrays for the mediaURL with the same output. There is another question similiar to this but the solution there did not work for me. I also made sure my session is open so its not that either.